# Assembly 8086; Floating Point Numbers, Add, Subtract

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, x87

I need some resources to get to know more about numbers with floating point, I need to code add and subtract operations for that kind of numbers in [emu8086](http://www.emu8086.com/) environment ....

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Well, the original 8086 didn't have floating point.  That function was provided by the (optional) 8087 "coprocessor".  But the 8087 instruction opcodes were rigged to "trap" if the 8087 was not present so that floating point could be emulated with subroutines in the 8086.

Comment: And it's unclear -- are you coding in 8086 assembler on an emulator, or writing an 8086 emulator?

Comment: The Intel 8086 processor doesn't contain a floating point unit. Perhaps you meant the 8087 coprocessor, or the generic x86 instruction set?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8087) is always a good source of info, though it doesn't give the actual instruction set or floating-point layout.  (Though it turns out the instructions are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#x87_floating-point_instructions).

Comment: I know what you all mean guys but my question isn't that I need an order like 'add' or 'mov' to do that, I need an algorithm to write a code, a program to do what I'm looking for, I didn't ask for a code, because I'm a college student, I want to have a research and then write the code on my self so....By the way this is the program I'm working with :
http://www.emu8086.com/

Comment: At the risk of beating a dead horse, I'd add one more question: how accurately do you intend to emulate an 8087? Is it important that you produce results that are bit-for-bit identical, or just that you produce answers to around the same precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, emu8086 does *not* emulate a machine with an 8087 FPU.

Any floating-point you do has to be pure software, not using `fld` / `fadd` / `fstp` or any of the usual legacy<sup>1</sup> [x87 instructions](http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html).

If you want to use FP instructions in real mode, your best bet is an emulator like DOSBox or BOCHS that emulate a more recent x86 + x87, not emu8086.  This also has the advantage of letting you use more convenient instructions like `imul ax, 1234` instead of having to use 1-operand `mul`.

If you are stuck with emu8086 (or a real 8086 microcontroller), most problems can be solved with [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), not actually floating point:  treat a fixed number of bits as the fractional part.  This is easier to do in software with integer instructions.  But it still lets you represent numbers like `1.25`.

---

Footnote 1:  In modern x86, the x87 FPU is obsolete; we use SSE and SSE2 now for scalar and SIMD FP math, unless 80-bit precision is actually needed.  emu8086 of course doesn't have this either.  Modern x86 CPUs of course still support x87 instructions; being backwards compatible with existing binaries is x86's primary reason for still existing.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the addition and subtractions for floating point numbers if you store each number in an array of size 2.

The first block of the array can be the base number and the second being the decimal number (implemented as a regular integer of course).

This may not be the most efficient way, but it is surely possible.  Your algorithm will have to take into consideration the way the numbers are stored then perform the ADD and SUB instructions.

You said you didn't want code so I won't post an example, but hopefully this gives you an idea how you can do this on a processor that has no floating point unit.

Comment: Yep, this is one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The 8086 processor doesn't have a floating point unit. There was a floating point coprocessor called the 8087, which was meant to be used with the 8086.

You can see the instruction set for the original 8087 here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#x87_floating-point_instructions

Comment: I know what you mean Polynomial but my question isn't that I need an order like 'add' or 'mov' to do that, I need an algorithm to write a code, a program to do what I'm looking for, I didn't ask for a code, because I'm a college student, I want to have a research and then write the code on my self so....

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you looking for an IDE? A compiler? A reference book?

Comment: Sorry I made you confused, to make it clear:
I need a code which does the operations such add and Subtract on numbers with floating point and also I want the code to get compiled on an emulator such emu8086:http://www.emu8086.com/........