# is there any way to calculate x^y in emu8086? (x is an integer and y is a float)

Tags: assembly, floating-point, emu8086

I have a homework which will be calculate PCB trace width. How can I calculate this formula in emu8086?(Sorry for my bad english)

k is a float,temp_rise is an integer, b is a float, c is a float

[image]

Comment: Peter Cordes tagged your question with the [tag:x87] tag, however, according to a comment to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67359290/non-integer-powers-in-x86-assembly?noredirect=1#comment119145830_67359290), only 8086 (**without** FPU) instructions shall be used. Does your teacher allow you to use FPU (8087) instructions?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know "emu8086". But according to your own answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289777/assembly-8086-floating-point-numbers-add-subtract), "emu8086" emulates a machine with 8086 CPU but without 8087 FPU. So the tag [tag:x87] should be wrong...

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Oh, I'd forgotten that, and tagged partly based on the answer and the fact that question title asks how to handle a general `float` exponent.  But if `c` is a whole number, then taking the nth root is something you could do with integer math without just emulating software floating-point.  Seems unlikely that beginner emu8086 homework would actually expect writing soft-FP routines.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I don't know much about emu8086 either.  I think I loaded it up once under WIINE, but basically everything I know about it is from SO Q&As about it.  I'm not at all impressed; e.g. some weird stuff like letting `mov [si], 1234` assemble with some default operand-size instead rejecting it as ambiguous, and other poor design choices or bugs in its built-in assembler.  And it's closed-source and AFAIK not being maintained / updated.

Comment: Firstly thanks to all of you. I editted my post because you are right x87 tag is wrong for my question. And also I did some research on the internet with x87 instructions. But I need to do these calculations with emu8086 and without FPU how I can handle this I still don't know. But thanks again.

Comment: Is `c` a *specific* constant?  It's a lot of work to implement your formula as written, in a way that works for any arbitrary floating-point `c` value.  (And I say this as someone fully comfortable with assembly language; I can write it about as easily as C.  And it's still a lot of work to write a software floating-point power or inverse-power function.  Even just FP multiply with pure software is non-trivial compared to fixed-point.)  Could you write the algorithm in C using only `int32_t` / `uint32_t`?  (asm has a carry flag for working with ints wider than a register.)

Comment: c takes 2 number according to the input that taken from the user (c=1/0.7 or c=1/0.725). Also after some time, my laboratory research assistant gives a hint about homework. The hint is taylor series. I think, I can use taylor series to calculate float exponentials but this will cause some errors because center of taylor series can change largely due to given formula above.

Answer (score 2):

You would usually use the `f2xm1` and `fyl2x` instructions.  Somthing like

```
fld   y
fild  x
fyl2x    // compute y*log2(x)
f2xm1    // compute 2**(y*log2(x)) - 1 (which is x**y - 1)
fld1
faddp    // top of stack is now x**y
fstp  result
```